# Find $M⊥$, the orthogonal complement of $M$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise is as follows:

> Find the Orthogonal complement of $M = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 2x_2^2+x_1=0\}$.

I know that I have to find another vector such that the dot product between them results in zero, but what is it in the same group of exercises with projections? How do I find out what are the coordinates of my vector $\underline x$?

Comment: What is the vector that generates the linear space $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more familiar setting, let $x_2=y$ and $x_1=x$. Then when $2y+x=0$, this implies $y=-\frac{x}{2}$. The perpendicular line is $y=2x$ since the perpendicular line has slope of negative reciprocal. This line has basis $\{[1,2]^T\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm sorry, I had to edit my questions, it was $2x_2^2$ instead of $2x_2$

Comment: $M$ is not linear in that case. Also, the formatting is off. I see question marks surrounding the definition of $M$.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it,, it looks good on my end. If it isn't linear, how do I show it does not have an orthogonal complement?

Comment: Should it be $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: 2x_2^2+x_1=0\}$?

Comment: yes it should be like you said

Comment: Are you sure there's not more to the question? The space $M$ is a parabola; it's not linear.

Comment: I think my book has a formatting error, it doesn't make sense, I will keep your answer for when $x_2$ is not quadratic

Comment: why do you transpose the answer?

Comment: @Pirategull : That's a good question. In general, vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are written as column vectors so that square matrices can multiply by them. However, it's easier to typeset and takes up less space to write a column vector as the transpose of a row vector.